# Ruby Rails calculate when submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have this form:

```
<%= form_for(@candy) do |f| %>
  <div class="">
    <%= current_user.totalcandy %>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <%= f.label :candy, 'add a candy' %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :candy%>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <%= f.submit('ADD') %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

how do i add that input value into totalcandy and save it? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `class=""`? You can just omit the `class` attribute if you don't have a value for it.

Comment: create a virtual attribute to the model and add an input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting confused with how Rails works

1. Rails is server-side
2. You're trying to calculate client-side
3. You have to process them separately

---

**[Modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity)**

You'll have to calculate this on the back-end (once you've submitted the form)

Rails views are there to show an HTML page, and won't change unless a [request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is performed to the server

In keeping with Rail's modular structure, you need to keep your logic in your controller, your inputs in your views, and your data manipulation in your models. Therefore, you only need to pass the different `Candy's` to your controller, allowing *it* to sum the total:

```
#app/views/candys/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(@candy) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :candy, 'Add a candy' %>
    <%= f.number_field :candy%>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/candys_controller.rb
def new 
    @candy = Candy.new
end 

def create
    @candy = Candy.new(candy_params)
    @candy.save

    @total_candy = #your logic here
end

private

def candy_params
    params.require(:candy).permit(:candy)
end
```